# How to add a Column Total to the Current Time

Tags: excel

Is it possible to sum the total time column and add it to the current time using Excel? I need an estimate of the time i would be completing these job assignment. The way to do it would be getting total time per batch type and adding it to the current time.

```
Batch Type  Items   Time Per Batch  Total Time  Employees   Total Hours 
Checks        13       0:06         1:18           8        0:09
Dis           0                                    0    
Misc          6                                    8    
Multi         0        0:03         0:00           8        0:00
Singles       40       0:01         0:40           8        0:05
Summ Bills    7        0:12         1:27           8        0:10
```

Answer (score 1):

Use:

```
=SUM(D2:D7)+NOW()
```

this will not be live and will require hitting F9 or any other change that forced Excel to re-calculate the sheet to update.

[image]

Answer (score -1):

In addition to what [Scott Craner](https://stackoverflow.com/users/4851590/scott-craner)'s answer, I'd suggest making a macro button that presses F9 if you are doing this for an end user.

Comment: This would be better suited as a comment under @ScottCraners answer. This is not a  solution to the original ask :)

Comment: I could not comment under Scott's because my reputation is under 50 :(